# Let A be an uncountable set and let C be a countable set with A∩C=∅. Show that |A U C| = |A|

Tags: logic

Let A be an uncountable set and let C be a countable set with A∩C=∅. Show that |A U C| = |A|

hint: you can use the fact that A contains an infinite countable subset B

Comment: Could you solve the problem if $A$ were itself countably infinite? Say, $A=\{1,2,3,...\}$.

Comment: This is not a site for homework service. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  A countable subset $B = \{b_1, b_2, b_3, .....\}$ can itself be partitioned into two disjoint countable subset $B_E = \{b_2, b_4, b_6,...\}$ and $B_O = \{b_1,b_3, b_5....\}$.

So $A \cup C = (A\setminus B) \cup B \cup C$.

And $A = (A\setminus B) \cup B_E \cup B_O$.

> So in mapping $A\cup C$ to $A$ why don't you you map $A\setminus B$ to $A\setminus B$;  And map $B$ to $B_E$; and map $C$ to $B_O$.

.

> (Assuming text means countable to mean countable and infinite.  But even if $C$ is finite we can still you use the same countably infinite $B$.  We just have to partition $B$ inot to disjoint sets, one finite with the same cardinality of $A$, and the other..... everything else.)